# How do you create a program launcher with administrative privileges using Alacarte?

Tags: synaptic, privileges, alacarte

How do you create a program launcher with Alacarte (Main Menu) that has administrative privileges? I ask because I seem to have deleted the launcher for Synaptic Package Manager and whenever I start it with the command, 'Synaptic' I have to run it without administrative privileges.

As in, what do I type into, 'Command' to run Synaptic Package Manager with administrative privileges in the following screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
gksudo -u root <program_name>
```

or

```
gksudo -k -u root <program_name>
```

to run `<program_name>` as the root user.

See the [manpage for the `gksudo` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gksudo) for more information.

Comment: 'gksudo program name' works by itself too.

Comment: Indeed, there's no need to specify `-u root`, without the `-u` option `gksu` and `gksudo` default to running the command as `root`.

Comment: As stated, `gksudo synaptic` is sufficient. However, the default command is `synaptic-pkexec`; you can try that to see if you prefer it (the difference occurs when you enter your password).